Space complexity when looping through string slice in Python
Normally when creating a string slice in Python, it takes O(n) space:
s = "hello world"
s[1:] # O(n)

When you loop through a string slice, it makes sense that it also takes O(n) space:
s = "hello_world"

for c in s[1:]: # O(n)?
  ...


However we can achieve the same loop with indexing, which should take O(1) space since we use range:
s = "hello_world"

for i in range(1, len(s)): # O(1)
  ...

If this is all true, then looping through a string slice always worsens the space complexity over indexing.
It would be kind of a bummer if we can't use nice syntax like for c in s[1:]: because of this.
My feeling is that the interpreter just handles both of these cases the same and since it's a for loop, s[1:] doesn't necessarily return a string, but an iterator instead. However, I have no concrete evidence of this at all.
What is the space complexity of looping through string slice?
Ideally, I'd like an explanation straight from the documentation, but I haven't found any clear explanation of this.
I don't know how to track the amount of memory/space used in a python script, so I'm not sure how to test this in the real world.

Don't avoid string slicing at all times because it copies, be mindful of the context. Yes, a string slice uses O(n) auxiliary space, but it still uses O(n) total space even if you don't copy, because you still need to store the original string.

CPython doesn’t currently (as of 3.12) do anything intelligent here; if you slice a string to iterate over it, it will create a copy. Yes, this kind of thing is a bit of a bummer.
One way to measure is with tracemalloc:
import tracemalloc

LARGE_STRING = "a" * 10_000_000
SMALL_STRING = "b" * 100

tracemalloc.start()

for c in …_STRING[1:]:
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    break

tracemalloc.stop()

for stat in snapshot.statistics("traceback"):
    print(stat)

For LARGE_STRING,

…/test.py:8: size=9766 KiB, count=2, average=4883 KiB

and for SMALL_STRING,

…/test.py:8: size=196 B, count=2, average=98 B

bytes and bytearrays can be used with the built-in memoryview, whose slices are references instead of copies, but there’s no built-in equivalent for strings. Even itertools.islice is wasteful, since it takes O(offset) time unnecessarily.

Do you know what the count=2, average=4883 KiB means? It only does that once, no? Also strange: If I remove the loop and just do the slicing and the snapshot, it doesn't report anything. Any idea why?

@nocomment: There are two traced allocations of any kind – the second one being the iterator (I think). The average isn’t very meaningful. The snapshot only reports live allocations, so if you slice without storing the result anywhere, the result will be freed immediately and won’t show up. (This would also happen if you moved take_snapshot after the loop.)

Ah, ok. I usually look at get_traced_memory()[1], so I'm used to thinking of peak memory usage.

Thanks so much for the thorough answer and testing! Super helpful

Python does not examine the context of a slicing operation to optimize it. A slice retrieval will perform the same operation whether you loop over the result, store it in a variable, pass it to a function, or even just discard the output. for c in s[1:] has O(n) space complexity.
For the specific case of skipping the first item of a string, you might do something like
it = iter(s)
next(it)
for c in it:
    ...

which retrieves an iterator and explicitly skips the first element, or
import itertools

for c in itertools.islice(s, 1, None):
    ...

which uses itertools.islice to do pretty much the same thing.
Note that itertools.islice is not an efficient way to produce arbitrary iterator-based slices of arbitrary sequences. It operates through the iterator protocol, not through indexing, so it has no way to efficiently jump to arbitrary indices of a sequence you pass it. If you try to replicate s[1000000:] with itertools.islice, it will have to iterate over the first 1000000 characters of s before it can produce any output. This is fine when you're only skipping 1 character, but not efficient for trying to skip deep into a sequence.

Oh this is a great alternative! Thank you!
